# adding more IP's to my DHCP scope

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

Our DHCP server is running out of addresses in its range.  How can I increase the range?

We have Windows Server 2008r2 as a DC\DNS\DHCP server.

current scope range 10.220.120.1 - 10.220.120.254 (255.255.255.0) (starting IP 10.220.120.150-253)

All servers sub nets are already set to (255.255.254.0) (ip's from 10.220.120.2-149)

How would i increase the host range?  Do I just change the range to 10.220.120.1 -10.220.121.253 (255.255.254.0) releash all ips first.. so that clients get the new subnet?

Any help would be great thanks. ( this stuff makes my head hurt! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about create a new scope, or you can configure the lease time for ip address.

Comment: going to be making alot of updates to the network soon so i think i will hold off untill then.. ( new ip phones and switches..vlans)